# How to get all check box values,if user selects any one check box?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

**I had Check boxes as below:**

`input name="rec type" type="check box" value="1"` **one**

`input name="rec type" type="check box" value="2"`  **Two**

`input name="rec type" type="check box" value="3"` **Three**

`input name="rec type" type="check box" value="4"` **Four**

Now if i checked on any one check box,i have to get all check box values as array and if user checks on check box one,i need to disable two and four Check boxes.

Any inputs on how to do this?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: refer this and do accordingly :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event

Comment: try to post your problem  as code format

Comment: do you want get the values as `arr={'1','2','3','4'}` or `arr={'checked','Unchecked','checked','checked'}` ?

Comment: Um, name can not have a space and checkbox is one word.

Answer (score 0):

add a class `class="ckbox"`to your all input box and try this :

```
<input name="rec type" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ckbox" />
```

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ckbox').click(function () {
            $('.ckbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All checkbox values in an array

```
var values = $("[name='rectype']").map(function(){return this.value}).get();
```

To disable, use onchange and check if the first checkbox is checked

```
var isOneChecked = $("[name='rectype'][value='1']").is(":checked");
```

than you can disable them using prop

```
$("[name='rectype'][value='4']").prop("disabled", isOneChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"/>one
<input type="checkbox" class="odd" value="2"/>two
<input type="checkbox" value="3"/>three
<input type="checkbox" class="odd" value="4"/>four
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   var myArr = []; 
   if($(this).val() == "1"){
      $('.odd').prop('disabled',!$('.odd').attr('disabled'));
   }

   $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
     myArr.push($(this).val());
   }); 
   alert(myArr);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnwS4/)

Comment: i tried above code,but i am getting error as:Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method

Comment: Give give me suggestion,that i need any jquery libraries i need to add??

Comment: you just need to add `Jquery` `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`, that's enough.