# how to alert the value of checkbox when it's checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to alert the value of a specific input[checkbox] when an input[checkbox] is checked.
I have many input checkbox. so when it's checked, alert will fire.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
....
```

Comment: `$(':checkbox').change(function(){if(this.checked)alert(this.value)});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery checkbox change and click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert($(this).val())
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
```