# Working with checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write code that displays an `alert` when a checkbox is checked but it's not working. I have tried different code online but still can't get it to work. Could anyone please help me. Thank you.

```
<div id="filterBox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="one" />
    <label for="one">One </label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="two" />
    <label for="two">Two </label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="three" />
    <label for="three">Three </label>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#one').is(":checked")) {
        console.log("testing");
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap your checking code in a `.change` handler for the element. The way you have it now, the check runs only once when the document is finished rendering. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Something like `$("#one").change(function() { .... });` (but still inside the document.ready handler).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery checkbox change and click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the click event. You can try as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if ($('#one').is(":checked")) {
        console.log("testing");
    }
  });
});
```

Or you can use a change event as follows as suggested by @Rory McCrossan.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if ($('#one').is(":checked")) {
        console.log("testing");
    }
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle sample is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/hsyz087e/)

Comment: Use `change` when dealing with checkbox and radio elements for accessibility purposes.

Comment: Yes we can use that too. I will add it in the answer. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").change(function(){
      if ( $(this).prop('checked') == true ) {
        console.log("testing");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, your method also works for me

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of creating 3 different conditions,

you can use this one for all

add this javascript

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

if ($('#'+this.id).is(":checked")) {
    console.log(this.id + " is checked");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {             
          alert(this.id);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to attach a click event to your checkbox, also following will avoid specific checkbox check. Each checkbox click event will be handled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //attach click on each checkbox
   $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
       // if the current checkbox is checked then you can do what you want!
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("testing");
       }
   });
});
```