# Ruby on Rails: updating model when checkbox is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, checkbox, models

I got projects and todos inside them, todos have checkbox & text, so when I change the checkbox the whole model must be updated without any buttons.

Here is my project on heroku: https://polar-scrubland-30279.herokuapp.com/

index.html.erb ( I know that I'm not the best code speller)

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="project">
      <%= form_for(local_assigns[:project] || project) do |f| %>

        <div class="project-header">
          <h2> <%= f.object.title %> </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="project-todos">
          <%= f.fields_for(:todos) do |tf| %>
            <div class="todo">
              <div class="todo--checkbox">
                <%= tf.check_box :isCompleted %>
              </div>
              <div class="todo--text">
                <%= tf.object.text %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my ProjectsController:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:foo, :bar, todos_attributes: [:isCompleted, :text])
  end

end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**The question is:** how do I connect my form with my controller, and change todo's boolean variable when checkbox is checked/uncheked. I've tried some variants, but there is need a refresh button, which I don't wanna have.

GitHub - https://github.com/NanoBreaker/taskmanager

Comment: You could use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Here is a high level idea, have a class those checkboxes, in the javascript have a trigger for that checkbox. On that trigger, call an api to update the field in the controller.

Comment: You have to use 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event 
to catch chackbox change event

Comment: @gates Thanks guys, I'll try to use that information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 
   [jQuery checkbox change and click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event) 
to catch checkbox change event,

further you can use ajax request 
   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ on the change event,

in the ajax request use path to update method in Projects controller.

Note that you have to put the path in file config/routes.rb,
something like this:

post 'url' => 'projects#update'