# I want to get the checkboxes checked on edit form which i have checked on Add form using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not able to get the logic of checkbox checked on edit time(No database only static) please help me out

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject" value="maths">Maths
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject" value="chemistry">Chemistry</td>
<button onclick="onEditPressed(' + index + ')">Edit</button><br/><button onclick="deleteTableRow('+ index + ')">Delete</button>

<script>
  function onEditPressed(index) {
    selectedIndex = index;
    var stuObj = localStorage.studentsRecord;
    studentsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.studentsRecord);
    console.log(studentsArray);
    var stuObj = studentsArray[index];
    var checkboxes = stuObj.subject;
    document.getElementById("firstname").value = stuObj.firstname;
    document.getElementById("lastname").value = stuObj.lastname;
    document.getElementById("rollnum").value = stuObj.rollnum;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("subject");
    document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "Update";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This pretty easy, Either you can go via the JQuery route - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event or Plain JS way - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp . I suggest you do your research first and then post here.

Answer (score 0):

use querySelector

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.subject:checked');
```

it'll return an array of selected checkboxes