# ABP Jquery not catching checkbox change

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, abp

Using ABP Commercial and in a generated page I have 2 checkboxes, but I am unable to get the change event of them.

Here is the generated code for the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Permanent Resident Australia field is required." id="Prospectus_IsPermanentResidentAustralia" name="Prospectus.IsPermanentResidentAustralia" value="true" class="custom-control-input ">
```

I have tried a number of ways to get the change event.

```
$("#Prospectus_IsPermanentResidentAustralia").change(function () {
  $('#permAusDate').toggle();
    });

  $('#Prospectus_IsPermanentResidentAustralia').on("change", function () {
            $('#permAusDate').toggle();
   
});
```

Also tried it this way.

```
$(('#IsInternational').val).change(function () {
    if (this.checked != true) {
        $("#InternationalStudent").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#InternationalStudent").show();
    }
});
```

If I do this below, it works - the toggle is succesful - but naturally throws an error as change isn't a function as its missing the ()

```
 var permResidentAus = $('Prospectus.IsPermanentResidentAustralia').change;
$('permResidentAus ').on("change", function () {
           $('#permAusDate').toggle();
 
});
```

What am I missing in ABP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery checkbox change and click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event)

Comment: Can you be generating the page dynamically? Did you try $(document).on('change','#Prospectus_IsPermanentResidentAustralia', function(e){ $('#permAusDate').toggle();})

Comment: this has nothing to do with ABP. You can use jQuery  `on` `change` to subscribe the change event.